# cancel all $timeouts on route change

Tags: angularjs, timeout

```
            angular.forEach(response.jobs, function(job) {
                fetchStatus(job);
            });
    var fetchStatus = function (job) {
        $http
            .get('http://monterey.dev/checkStatus/' + $scope.sessionId + '/' + job.jobId)
            .success(function (response) {
                job[job.jobId] = response;

                if (response.status !== 'Completed' && response.status !== 'Aborted' && response.status !== 'Failed') {
                    $scope.dataTimeout = $timeout(function () {
                        fetchStatus(job)
                    }, 1000);
                }
            })
            .error (function () {
                $scope.dataTimeout = $timeout(function () {
                    fetchStatus(job)
                }, 1000);
            });
    };
```

here is the destroy function, I want to cancel all the $scope.dataTimeout. At present it is canceling only $timeout.

$scope.$on("$destroy", function () {

```
$timeout.cancel($scope.dataTimeout);

    });
```

Comment: Note: `.success().error()` are deprecated. It is better to use `.then(function(response){ ... }, function(error){...})`.. Angular Docs => `The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been deprecated. Use the standard then method instead.`

Comment: We are currently still using AngularJS v1.3.15, I think it still supports the .success().error(). But anyways thanks for the info.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are doing this in a loop, every iteration will over write `$scope.dataTimeout` so it will only contain reference to the very last `$timeout`

You would need to create an array instead to be able to access them all.

```
 var dataTimeout=[];
```

Then in the loop:

```
var timeOut = $timeout(function () {
       fetchStatus(job);
}, 1000);

dataTimeout.push( timeOut );
```

And finally to cancel them all loop over the array and cancel each instance:

```
$scope.$on("$destroy", function () {
    dataTimeout.forEach(function(timeout){
       $timeout.cancel(timeout);    
    });
});
```